# My modded server only lets people on my LAN to join

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, mods, minecraft-mods

So I've been following a tutorial to set this thing up and so far these are the problems that I have found: No one else that isn't on my WIFI can't join.

I have port forwarded my local IP and I cannot set the servers IP or it will not start, I don't know if i have to port forward my public IP too but i just get no option to do that. Also I have no idea how to set how much ram it is allowed to use please help me.

The only things I've tried are factory resetting my computer 3-4 times (I've done both vanilla and modded but I am trying to do a modded server) and used different methods to download the server and each show up with the same result that only LAN can join but no one else can.

Please help me I really don't know what else to do. Also if i missed something that would help figuring out what the problem is I would be happy to provide it, Thanks :).

Comment: You say you followed a tutorial. If you could link to that tutorial, I'm sure people would be able to give you more relevant help. As it is now, you're likely to get answers that have already been covered by the tutorial and are therefore not helpful.

Comment: Please stop this. Read the comments on the original question and fix that instead. Repeated and knowing rule breaking can result in a ban.

Answer (score 1):

People connecting to you need to connect to your public IP, not your local IP; if they're using (for example) `192.168.0.114:25565`, they should instead be using `<public IP>:25565`. Port forwarding options should be in your router's configuration page, and you should be forwarding 25565 at your local IP. If all of this is true and the server still isn't working, confirm you have the correct local IP with the `ipconfig` command in Command Prompt.

Comment: Note: `ipconfig` is Windows. On macOS and Linux, the command is `ifconfig` instead.

Comment: So they do use my public IP (sorry if i didnt mention that) and it still dosent work